# Empty dataframe when importing CSV file

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, import

Importing data from CSV file doesn't work. Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Result1': [1552, 3954, 7495], 'Result2': [1552, 3950, 1559]}, 
index=['Customer1', 'Customer2', 'Customer3'])
```

I want to search for any customer who has a particular value in any column:

```
results_to_keep = ['155101', '1551011']
df2 = df[df.isin(results_to_keep)]
df3 = df2.dropna(axis=0, how='all')

print(df3)
```

It works for supplied data. But when I instead import from CSV file I get an empty dataframe. How to import a CSV file to the same format as data above?

EDIT: here's a cut & paste from the input file; I've truncated the number of results columns & rows for brevity

```
    Customer Reference  Profile Name    Score   Band Text   Result1 Result2 Result3
038ff126-1ed5-4a96-bb34-3f4b595228d3    UK  1200    APPROVED    155261  155101  155151
87529660    Germany 1111    APPROVED    2289528 401126  401102
37a52968-8093-41e5-8a2e-6bd251d0666d    UK  2200    APPROVED    155261  155101  155151
1.39E+08    Germany 1111    APPROVED    2283524 2283525 2282111
1d45f78b-01c5-4007-8f8c-a9fb845cba1f    UK  1300    Fail    155261  155101  155151
a56b590b-b8bd-4e56-987e-f801a37e487d    UK  1300    Fail    155261  155101  155151
1.39E+08    Germany 2221    APPROVED    2283525 2282111 2282100
```

Comment: Verify the way you save your CSV file. The index will be replaced with a column and a new index added.

Comment: you must provide a [mcve].

Comment: Question updated with sample input. Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

Failing to read a column as an index results in an empty DataFrame. Assuming data in CSV file like:

|  |  | Result 1 | Result2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Customer1 | 1552 | 7495 |
| 1 | Customer2 | 3954 | 3950 |
| 2 | Customer3 | 7495 | 1559 |

The Customer columns should be read as an index:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=0)

results_to_keep = ['1552', '1551']
df2 = df[df.isin(results_to_keep)]
df3=df2.dropna(axis=0, how='all')

print(df3)
```

Result:

|  | Result 1 | Result2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 | 1552 | 1552 |

Comment: Thanks for your input @roxy, but this hasn't changed the result I'm getting.  Not sure if I need to share my input file?

Comment: Sure, I could recommend that.

Comment: I've updated the question with a sample. Thanks